# Do any Heavy Gear books cover landships?

Tags: vehicles, heavy-gear

I only have a couple of Heavy Gear books but they are some mentions of landships existing.  I haven't found any stats for them.  It's possible they are in a more miniatures focused product but I was wondering if there any books that specifically detail them and their uses?  Books with stats would be a plus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On DreamPod 9's [Downloads Page](http://www.dp9.com/downloads) you can find some record sheets for Landships under *HG RPG & Tactical -> Heavy Gear Tactical*. Additionally, it appears that if you use the Vehicle Construction Rules (Vehicle Construction System, VCS Worksheets) you can craft a Landship by creating the largest scale of ship.